# Iteratively generate datablocks in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to iteratively generate datablocks, where the name of the datablock is build up inside the loop?
Let's assume I have three fruits (in reality there are more):

```
array namelist[3] = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple']
```

I want to create three datablocks with the names `$apple_data`, `$banana_data` and `$pineapple_data`, so I tried the following:

```
do for [i=1:|namelist|] {
set table '$'.namelist[i]."_data"
plot ...
unset table
}
```

Unfortunately, instead of datablocks gnuplot created files with these names in the working directory. I guess gnuplot is checking whether the first character after `set table` is a `$`?

My second attempt was to remove the apostrophes around $:

```
set table $.namelist[i]."_data"
```

But this raised the weird error "Column number or datablock line expected", pointing at the period right after $.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?
The reason for all this is that I read in the banana/apple data files with a lengthy path, apply some lengthy calculations within `using`, and reuse these for lots of successive `stats` and `plot` commands. I would like to avoid having to hard-code and copy-paste the same long path and the cumbersome using command over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood your detailed intention.
If you only want to avoid typing (or copy pasting) a lengthy path again and again, simply use variables:

```
FILE1 = 'C:/Dir1/SubDir1/SubSubDir1/SubSubSubDir1/File1' 
FILE2 = 'C:/Dir2/SubDir2/SubSubDir2/SubSubSubDir2/File2'
plot FILE1 u 1:2, FILE2 u 1:2
```

Anyway, you asked for dynamically generated datablocks. One way which comes to my mind is using `evaluate`, check `help evaluate`. Check the example below as a starting point, which can probably be simplified.

**Code:** (simplified thanks to @Eldrad's comment)

```
### dynamically generate some datablocks
reset session

myNames   = 'apple banana pineapple'
myName(i) = word(myNames,i)

N = words(myNames)
set samples 11

do for [i=1:N] {
    eval sprintf('set table $%s_data',myName(i))
        plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)) w table
    unset table
}

plot for [i=1:N] sprintf('$%s_data',myName(i)) w lp pt 7 ti myName(i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `eval` does the trick. In my code above it is sufficient to change `set table '$'.namelist[i].'_data'` to `eval 'set table $'.namelist[i].'_data'` and then everything works; the plot command can be written iteratively as well: `plot for [i=1:|namelist|] '$'.namelist[i].'_data' w lp pt 7`.
My intention is to later label minima/maxima, draw lines from the maximum of one data set to the minimum of an other data set and so on, (with extensive usage of `stats`), while keeping the code short.

Comment: @Eldrad yes, thanks for your suggestion, it can be simplified. I adjusted my answer in a similar way.